# how to remove operator-lifecycle-manager from operatorhub.io

Tags: kubernetes-operator

I have installed an operator from operatorhub.io. Now how do you remove the operator lifecycle manager again?

Install:

```
curl -sL https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/v0.22.0/install.sh | bash -s v0.22.0
```

Delete:?

Comment: why do you want to remove OLM? It will automatically keep the operator you installed up to date.

Comment: Thank , the operator I installed did not work, so I just wanted to remove OLM again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [operator-sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/installation/) installed you can simply run

```
operator-sdk olm uninstall
```

Otherwise, taking a look at the OLM github repo's [Makefile](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/blob/c652154fd7eeb72a23f78856b2cbade775efad41/Makefile#L256), you can follow these steps:

```
    - kubectl delete -f deploy/upstream/quickstart/crds.yaml
    - kubectl delete -f deploy/upstream/quickstart/olm.yaml
    - kubectl delete catalogsources.operators.coreos.com
    - kubectl delete clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com
    - kubectl delete installplans.operators.coreos.com
    - kubectl delete operatorgroups.operators.coreos.com subscriptions.operators.coreos.com
    - kubectl delete apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io v1.packages.operators.coreos.com
    - kubectl delete ns olm
    - kubectl delete ns openshift-operator-lifecycle-manager
    - kubectl delete ns openshift-operators
    - kubectl delete ns operators
    - kubectl delete clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-olm-edit
    - kubectl delete clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-olm-view
    - kubectl delete clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:operator-lifecycle-manager
    - kubectl delete clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:controller:operator-lifecycle-manager"
    - kubectl delete clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "olm-operator-binding-openshift-operator-lifecycle-manager"
```